# how can I convert string to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I am passing dictionary from python to java script,

when I print this dictionary in java script it gets printed as `string`,

I confirmed this by checking its type. I want to convert this string into
object so that I can access the key value pairs,

when I try to parse this string I am getting error

`data` object looks like this

```
{
 'AMARAJABAT': 'https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/AMARAJABAT21SEP710CE/15738370',
 'ASIANPAINT': 'https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/ASIANPAINT21SEP3300CE/16292866', 
 'ASTRAL'    :     'https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/ASTRAL21SEP2100CE/15201026',
 'AXISBANK'  :   'https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/AXISBANK21SEP800CE/16441858'
}
```

.

```
eventSource.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
    
    let data = e.data
    
    console.log(data)              // this prints dictionary
    console.log(typeof(data))      // this prints string
    
    let obj = JSON.parse(data)     // error at this line

    console.log(obj)    
}, true)
```

I am getting error as following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Replace **'** with **"**

Comment: @Radeanu No, never create it in the first place.

Comment: How are you '*passing dictionary*' from python to js?

Comment: i am yielding it like this yield f"id: 1\ndata: {stock_dic}\nevent: online\n\n"

Comment: @Radeanu i think you are talking about ' in data dictionary, how can i replace it?

Comment: @virajmane I mean how exactly do you *pass* an object between python and js? Are you using something like `eel`?

Comment: i am doing it using flask sse,

Comment: @eroot163pi Rolled back because this is a problem with their Python code.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I guess that's what happens when you ask a Python question and use the javascript tag :-P

Instead of trying to write your own JSON encoder with something like the

```
yield f"id: 1\ndata: {stock_dic}\nevent: online\n\n
```

from your comment, you should use a *proper* JSON encoder. Of course there's one for Python as well, even [**in** Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

So something like

```
yield json.dumps(mydictionary)
```

Comment: i see that username of person who posted that comment as radeanu and in your answer it is javascript boy, how is this possible?

Comment: I edited the page data before taking the screenshot. Partly to anonymize, partly as part of the joke (only a javascript fanboy would insinuate that Python isn't capable of creating proper JSON).

Comment: i figured that from fanboy, but still wanted to check if my eyes works fine:)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, this issue can be solved by replacing `'` by `''`.
before yielding dictionary I converted it to string using

```
json.dumps()
```

This way single quotations were replaced by double quoatation.

Comment: That way they were not "replaced", they were *never created* in the first place.